# Move canvas position in HTML5 puzzle game

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have downloaded a ready-made HTML5 [tile-swapping puzzle](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-an-html5-canvas-tile-swapping-puzzle--active-10747), but I am not getting how to change the canvas position.
If we change the canvas position by giving a margin to the body, the puzzle doesn't work. I'd like to align the puzzle to the middle of the page.

Here is a JSFiddle with the code for the puzzle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kilobyte/0ej6cv6w/

Here is an excerpt of the code you should examine, where I'm changing the margin:

```js
function Add(){
    alert("Congratulation...! You have Won...!!");
        var btn=document.createElement("input");
        btn.type="button";
        btn.id="mybutton";
        btn.value="Submit";
        btn.style.width="100px";
        btn.style.height="50px";
        btn.style.background="green";
        btn.style.margin="100px";
        document.body.appendChild(btn);
        var buttonid =document.getElementById("mybutton");
        buttonid.addEventListener('click', ButtonClick,false);
    }
    function gameOver(){
        document.onmousedown = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
        document.onmouseup = null;
        Add();  
    //initPuzzle();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Ok, seems like Firefox works, but chrome has a different behaviour. Im not going to rewrite the game, but i can give you a pointer on what to do. You need to edit the function called `onPuzzleClick()`, its located on on line 103 in the code. Thats where the click position is set (`_mouse.x` and `_mouse.y`). You need to find out whats different in chrome and set the correct position there, id advise looking at the left-margin and top-margin or some absolute position or similar

Comment: yes, canvas is working but at only top left corner ......change it's position it will not work.......for trying purpose you change image (200x200 pixel)

Comment: puzzle is working only at top left corner not other position...yes, canvas is working but at only top left corner ......change it's position it will not work.......for trying purpose you change image (200x200 pixel) or any small image .....after that apply css to canvas  and move it to perticular position that you want except top left corner you will see it will not work....

Comment: if i moved puzzle at any position on page it should work....please someone help me for this question......

Comment: If you put text-align:center on the wrapping element (in this case body) the canvas will center its position and still work as expected. Can you set up an example thats not working? For example with JSFiddle

Comment: yes, puzzle is positioning in center but it is not working....it meanse i am able to see that puzzle but when you click on it , image breaks in diffrent pieces  and when you will drag that pieces to make whole image that will not drag....... you try to solve that puzzle after positioning it to center........definately it will not work .....please sir help me......please........

Comment: well, to be sure i just solved the puzzle centered. Im not getting the behaviour you are talking about, its working fine in Firefox 40.0.2

Comment: thank you sir for helping me ......i am using google crome.......now i will try for  firefox.....lets hope everything will work properly as said...sir....Thaks a lot again.....

Comment: Thank you Zedd ...Its working in Firefox ....Can you please try it in crome ...and if possible please give me solution for crome......

Comment: then i suggest that you take that advice i stated, and post a new, more specific, question. That way maybe someone else will have time to rewrite your code or figure it out for you

Comment: no one is giving me ans they are telling question is repeate..Please if possible please explain your ans where and what to do...

Comment: @KailashTathe if you set up a JSfiddle demonstrating that exact problem, that people easily can test and write code in, it will not be marked as a duplicate and im sure someone will solve it for you.

Comment: Added a JSFiddle for you, feel free to fork or edit to demonstrate the problem. Hope this helps.

Comment: Better yet, put the code in a Stack Overflow snippet. Like the one I've included in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you quote in your question doesn't actually change the margin of the canvas. It assigns a margin to a button at the end of the game. But never mind that. In my demonstration below, I've removed the unnecessary button and I set the canvas margin with CSS.

We can fix the problem of the shifted canvas with the help of a function that calculates the offset of an HTML element with respect to an HTML element that encloses it:

```
function getOffset(element, ancestor) {
  var left = 0,
      top = 0;
  while (element != ancestor) {
    left += element.offsetLeft;
    top += element.offsetTop;
    element = element.parentNode;
  }
  return { left: left, top: top };
}
```

We also need a function that computes the mouse position with respect to the upper left corner of the page:

```
function getMousePosition (event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  if (event.pageX) {
    return { x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY };
  }
  return {
    x: event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft +
        document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
    y: event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop +
        document.documentElement.scrollTop
  };
}
```

In `setCanvas()`, we calculate and save the offset of the canvas relative to the page:

```
_canvas.offset = getOffset(_canvas, document.body);
```

Subsequently, when we need the mouse coordinates in `onPuzzleClick()` and `updatePuzzle()`, we take the canvas offset into account:

```
var position = getMousePosition(e);
_mouse.x = position.x - _canvas.offset.left;
_mouse.y = position.y - _canvas.offset.top;
```

Now the puzzle works correctly regardless of where the canvas is positioned:

```js
const PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY = 4;
const PUZZLE_HOVER_TINT = '#009900';

var _canvas;
var _stage;
var _img;
var _pieces;
var _puzzleWidth;
var _puzzleHeight;
var _pieceWidth;
var _pieceHeight;
var _currentPiece;
var _currentDropPiece;
var _mouse;

function getOffset(element, ancestor) {
  var left = 0,
      top = 0;
  while (element != ancestor) {
    left += element.offsetLeft;
    top += element.offsetTop;
    element = element.parentNode;
  }
  return { left: left, top: top };
}

function getMousePosition (event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  if (event.pageX) {
    return { x: event.pageX, y: event.pageY };
  }
  return {
    x: event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft +
        document.documentElement.scrollLeft,
    y: event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop +
        document.documentElement.scrollTop
  };
}

function init(){
    _img = new Image();
    _img.addEventListener('load',onImage,false);
    _img.src = "http://www.justvape247.com/ekmps/shops/justvape247/images/red-apple-natural-f.w-16946-p.jpg";
}

function onImage(e){
    _pieceWidth = Math.floor(_img.width / PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY)
    _pieceHeight = Math.floor(_img.height / PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY)
    _puzzleWidth = _pieceWidth * PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY;
    _puzzleHeight = _pieceHeight * PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY;
    setCanvas();
    initPuzzle();
}

function setCanvas(){
    _canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
    _stage = _canvas.getContext('2d');
    _canvas.width = _puzzleWidth;
    _canvas.height = _puzzleHeight;
    _canvas.style.border = "1px solid black";
    _canvas.offset = getOffset(_canvas, document.body);
}

function initPuzzle(){
    _pieces = [];
    _mouse = {x:0,y:0};
    _currentPiece = null;
    _currentDropPiece = null;
    _stage.drawImage(_img, 0, 0, _puzzleWidth, _puzzleHeight, 0, 0, _puzzleWidth, _puzzleHeight);
    createTitle("Click to Start Puzzle");
    buildPieces();
}

function createTitle(msg){
    _stage.fillStyle = "#000000";
    _stage.globalAlpha = .4;
    _stage.fillRect(100,_puzzleHeight - 40,_puzzleWidth - 200,40);
    _stage.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";//text color
    _stage.globalAlpha = 1;
    _stage.textAlign = "center";
    _stage.textBaseline = "middle";
    _stage.font = "20px Arial";
    _stage.fillText(msg,_puzzleWidth / 2,_puzzleHeight - 20);
}

function buildPieces(){
    var i;
    var piece;
    var xPos = 0;
    var yPos = 0;
    for(i = 0;i < PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY * PUZZLE_DIFFICULTY;i++){
        piece = {};
        piece.sx = xPos;
        piece.sy = yPos;
        _pieces.push(piece);
        xPos += _pieceWidth;
        if(xPos >= _puzzleWidth){
            xPos = 0;
            yPos += _pieceHeight;
        }
    }
    document.onmousedown = shufflePuzzle;
}

function shufflePuzzle(){
    _pieces = shuffleArray(_pieces);
    _stage.clearRect(0,0,_puzzleWidth,_puzzleHeight);
    var i;
    var piece;
    var xPos = 0;
    var yPos = 0;
    for(i = 0;i < _pieces.length;i++){
        piece = _pieces[i];
        piece.xPos = xPos;
        piece.yPos = yPos;
        _stage.drawImage(_img, piece.sx, piece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, xPos, yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
        _stage.strokeRect(xPos, yPos, _pieceWidth,_pieceHeight);
        xPos += _pieceWidth;
        if(xPos >= _puzzleWidth){
            xPos = 0;
            yPos += _pieceHeight;
        }
    }
    document.onmousedown = onPuzzleClick;
}

function shuffleArray(o){
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
}

function onPuzzleClick(e){
    var position = getMousePosition(e);
    _mouse.x = position.x - _canvas.offset.left;
    _mouse.y = position.y - _canvas.offset.top;
    _currentPiece = checkPieceClicked();
    if(_currentPiece != null){
        _stage.clearRect(_currentPiece.xPos,_currentPiece.yPos,_pieceWidth,_pieceHeight);
        _stage.save();
        _stage.globalAlpha = .9;
        _stage.drawImage(_img, _currentPiece.sx, _currentPiece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, _mouse.x - (_pieceWidth / 2), _mouse.y - (_pieceHeight / 2), _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
        _stage.restore();
        document.onmousemove = updatePuzzle;
        document.onmouseup = pieceDropped;
    }
}

function checkPieceClicked(){
    var i;
    var piece;
    for(i = 0;i < _pieces.length;i++){
        piece = _pieces[i];
        if(_mouse.x < piece.xPos || _mouse.x > (piece.xPos + _pieceWidth) || _mouse.y < piece.yPos || _mouse.y > (piece.yPos + _pieceHeight)){
            //PIECE NOT HIT
        }
        else{
            return piece;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function updatePuzzle(e){
    var position = getMousePosition(e);
    _mouse.x = position.x - _canvas.offset.left;
    _mouse.y = position.y - _canvas.offset.top;
    _currentDropPiece = null;
    _stage.clearRect(0,0,_puzzleWidth,_puzzleHeight);
    var i;
    var piece;
    for(i = 0;i < _pieces.length;i++){
        piece = _pieces[i];
        if(piece == _currentPiece){
            continue;
        }
        _stage.drawImage(_img, piece.sx, piece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, piece.xPos, piece.yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
        _stage.strokeRect(piece.xPos, piece.yPos, _pieceWidth,_pieceHeight);
        if(_currentDropPiece == null){
            if(_mouse.x < piece.xPos || _mouse.x > (piece.xPos + _pieceWidth) || _mouse.y < piece.yPos || _mouse.y > (piece.yPos + _pieceHeight)){
                //NOT OVER
            }
            else{
                _currentDropPiece = piece;
                _stage.save();
                _stage.globalAlpha = .4;
                _stage.fillStyle = PUZZLE_HOVER_TINT;
                _stage.fillRect(_currentDropPiece.xPos,_currentDropPiece.yPos,_pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
                _stage.restore();
            }
        }
    }
    _stage.save();
    _stage.globalAlpha = .6;
    _stage.drawImage(_img, _currentPiece.sx, _currentPiece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, _mouse.x - (_pieceWidth / 2), _mouse.y - (_pieceHeight / 2), _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
    _stage.restore();
    _stage.strokeRect( _mouse.x - (_pieceWidth / 2), _mouse.y - (_pieceHeight / 2), _pieceWidth,_pieceHeight);
}

function pieceDropped(e){
    document.onmousemove = null;
    document.onmouseup = null;
    if(_currentDropPiece != null){
        var tmp = {xPos:_currentPiece.xPos,yPos:_currentPiece.yPos};
        _currentPiece.xPos = _currentDropPiece.xPos;
        _currentPiece.yPos = _currentDropPiece.yPos;
        _currentDropPiece.xPos = tmp.xPos;
        _currentDropPiece.yPos = tmp.yPos;
    }
    resetPuzzleAndCheckWin();
}

function resetPuzzleAndCheckWin(){
    _stage.clearRect(0,0,_puzzleWidth,_puzzleHeight);
    var gameWin = true;
    var i;
    var piece;
    for(i = 0;i < _pieces.length;i++){
        piece = _pieces[i];
        _stage.drawImage(_img, piece.sx, piece.sy, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight, piece.xPos, piece.yPos, _pieceWidth, _pieceHeight);
        _stage.strokeRect(piece.xPos, piece.yPos, _pieceWidth,_pieceHeight);
        if(piece.xPos != piece.sx || piece.yPos != piece.sy){
            gameWin = false;
        }
    }
    if(gameWin){
        setTimeout(gameOver,500);
    }
}

function gameOver(){
    document.onmousedown = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
    document.onmouseup = null;
    alert("Congratulations...! You have Won...!!");
}

window.onload = init;
```

```css
#gameCanvas {
  margin: 20px 50px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
```